# Batch Files: list folders that contain a folder named region as a sub-folder

Tags: string, batch-file, echo, directory, region

I need batch code that will @echo the folder names, ONLY if they include a folder inside them that is called SPECIFICALLY "region".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /s/b/ad') do (
  if /i "%%~na" EQU "region" echo  %%~dpa
)
```

Comment: Almost. It doesn't handle directories with spaces in its name (folder `"region a"`) and doesn't handle directories with extension (`region.a`)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    for /r "c:\somewhere\toStart" %%f in (.) do (
        if /i "%%~nxf"=="region" echo "%%~dpf"
    )
```

For each folder in the structure begining at `c:\somewhere\toStart`, if name and extension of folder are `"region"`, then echo the drive and path to the folder (the folder containing the `region` folder).